# Will MYSQL work with ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can I use MYSQL to connect to ASP.NET website?

What would be advantages and disadvantages of this compared to using MS SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Here: http://tinyurl.com/26utxee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some main advantages in my opinion to SQL Server aside from support and tooling as Kirk Woll noted is that it scales really really well.

It also comes with a list of features that you might be interested including but hardly limited to

- SQL Server Integration Services which includes ETL and workflow tools
- SQL Server Reporting (which is what you think it is)
- CLR Assembly in side SQL so you can call C# from SQL code.

The major downside to SQL Server is that the licencing can be expensive and oddly a real pain to set it up.

Comment: Sure, SQL Server scales well, but I don't see how that can be an advantage vs MySQL.  With Facebook, Twitter, Quora, etc MySQL seems to scale just fine.

Comment: @RyanW Your point is taken, but I would like to point out that Facebook uses Memcache for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will... as long as you have an ADO.Net provider it will work in .Net

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET). Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of SQL Server is that it's prioritized by MS for support in their frameworks.  For example, Linq-To-SQL -- the SQL means SQL Server.  They never supported another DB.  Of course 3rd parties did (DbLinq, for example) but the support was fairly brittle and incomplete.  Linq-To-Entites offers a better chance at wider DB support, but you're still left with other databases generally being ignored and thus getting inferior support.

Answer (score 0):

The best advantage of MySQL is that MySQL is free! You can use its community edition at no charge. Besides, you can use free tools such as phpMyAdmin for web-based management of your database. Also you can use HeidiSQL as a free and full-featured tool for DB development, ops and maintance. From the otherside, interoperatability between .net and MS SQL Server is seemless and SQL Server is a mature product in comparision with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  I converted [NetworthIQ](http://www.networthiq.com) from SQL Server to MySQL after a few months in production and it worked great.

SQL Server does have better tooling support (Visual Studio, the MS ORMs, etc.) for a .NET application.  Choosing NHibernate as the ORM can mitigate some of that, it's relatively easy to migrate from one db to the other.

One bonus we got from the switch was enabling developers who were not from the MS world to do some db work, building complicated queries, scripts, etc.  Since MySQL can install on Mac, Windows, and Linux.

You may also be interested in this article: [Why Move to MySQL from Microsoft SQL Server?](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html)

But, with the Oracle acquisition of Sun and therefore MySQL, I'm not sure if I would make the same switch again. It's going to become harder to find/use a free MySQL.  I'd probably look at PostgreSQL as well.